# p-adic norm, Sets equal

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ a prime, and the p-adic norm $|x|_p = (\frac{1}{p})^{v_p(x)}$, with $v_p$ the p-adic valuation. Show that 
$$\{ |x|_p : x \in \mathbb{Q}_p \}  = \{ p^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
My question is how to show $\supseteq$? $\subseteq$ is easy!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\forall\;k\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;p^k=\left|\;\frac{1}{p^k}\;\right|_p\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, this way is easier!

Comment: Yup, I think so...it's just a matter of not getting confused with the fractions, positive/negative exponents and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: think about powers of $p$! $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}_p$, and you should know that $|\mathbb{Q}|_p$ is your desired set.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that given $k$ there is a $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert_p = p^k$. How about considering $x = p^{n}$. What would $n$ have to be?